# Please help in solving $ax^2 + bxy + cx + dy + e$ = 0

Tags: conic-sections, quadratic-forms

Sometime back when trying to work out how to solve $ax^2 - by^2 + cx - dy + e = 0$ I learned that the way to solve such forms is to 'square the terms' and give it the form $A^2 - B^2 - E = 0$, $A = ax + c/2$, $B = by + d/2$, $E = -e + (c/2)^2 + (d/2)^2$.

However I am not able to work out how to square the following equation - $ax^2 + bxy + cx + dy + e = 0$. I guessing I need to transform x and y to x' and y' such that the coefficient of $x'*y'$ is reduced to 0, but not sure how to do this.

Please help or advise.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to [rotate](http://mathamazement.com/Lessons/Pre-Calculus/09_Conic-Sections-and-Analytic-Geometry/rotation-of-axes.html) the conic section via an appropriate change of variables.

Comment: Thanks! Been through the link and it helps but now I have more queries. The link states the angle of rotation can be got through the relation $tan(t) = b/c-a$, another similar document suggested angle of rotation would be got by $cot (t) = a-c/b$. I think the former relation is correct since I tried both and the $b$ term got cancelled only by using the results from the 'tan' formula. However the bigger problem is that prior to rotation of the equation it produced a hyperbola. After rotation now I am getting an ellipse! Is this correct?

Comment: Ok solved the hyperbola to ellipse transform mystery. I was using $cos (t)$ instead of $cos (2t)$. Fixed this. Now I need to figure out how to solve the transformed equation to return a solution that maps back to give an integer solution for the original equation!